# AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = event.getSource() always returns null

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I'm trying to use AccessibilityNodeInfo but when I use event.getSource()  it always returns null, I try to read the editbox of the browsers here is my codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
static final String TAG = "RecorderService";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, RecorderService.class);
    startService(i);
}}
```

accessibilityServicecode which acts as a service:

```
public class RecorderService extends AccessibilityService {

static final String TAG = "RecorderService";

private String getEventType(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    switch (event.getEventType()) {
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED:
            return "TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED";
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED:
            return "TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED";
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED:
            return "TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED";
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_LONG_CLICKED:
            return "TYPE_VIEW_LONG_CLICKED";
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_SELECTED:
            return "TYPE_VIEW_SELECTED";
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED:
            return "TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED";
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED:
            return "TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED";
    }
    return "default";
}

private String getEventText(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (CharSequence s : event.getText()) {
        sb.append(s);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

    AccessibilityNodeInfo source = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        source = event.getSource();
        Log.v(TAG, "Source Accessibility node info: " + source);
    }

    Log.v(TAG, String.format(
            "onAccessibilityEvent: [type] %s [class] %s [package] %s [time] %s [text] %s",
            getEventType(event), event.getClassName(), event.getPackageName(),
            event.getEventTime(), getEventText(event)));
}
@Override
public void onInterrupt() {
    Log.v(TAG, "onInterrupt");
}

@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected();
    Log.v(TAG, "***********onServiceConnected");
    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    info.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.DEFAULT |
            AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_RETRIEVE_INTERACTIVE_WINDOWS |
            AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_REQUEST_ENHANCED_WEB_ACCESSIBILITY |
            AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_INCLUDE_NOT_IMPORTANT_VIEWS |
            AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_REPORT_VIEW_IDS;
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPES_ALL_MASK;
    info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;
    setServiceInfo(info);}}
```

acessbibility.xml:

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowStateChanged|typeViewHoverEnter|typeViewHoverExit|typeWindowContentChanged"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagIncludeNotImportantViews|flagRequestTouchExplorationMode|flagRequestEnhancedWebAccessibility|flagReportViewIds|flagRequestFilterKeyEvents"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"
android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true"
android:canRequestEnhancedWebAccessibility="true"
android:settingsActivity="com.recorderservice"
/>
```

Comment: By the way here is manifast.xml: <service android:name=".RecorderService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.RecorderService"
                android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config"/
        </service>

Comment: Why are you attempting to start your Accessibility Service from your activity?  I'm surprised that you are able to log anything given this approach, let alone catch event sources.

Comment: Would you mind to give me a exact clue that how can I do that since I am a new android developer.

Comment: You start your accessibility service by going into accessibility settings, and toggling this on/off switch associated with the given service.  Same way you would turn on TalkBack.

Comment: I did what you recommended to me, I removed these lines:
 Intent i = new Intent(this, RecorderService.class);
    startService(i);
it worked without them but still I have the same problem, event.getSource() returns null

Comment: I found out what was the problem, it was because of my bad configuration of my manifast : here is the correct one: 
<meta-data
                android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config"/> 
I named it incorrectly to android.RecorderService

Comment: You should post this as an answer, or remove the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was the problem, it was because of my bad configuration of my manifast :
here is the correct one:

I named it incorrectly to android.RecorderService