# My App Overlay gets visible when any app Edittext is active?Is it possible?

Tags: android

Whenever the edittext of any application clicked, whether its of fb, whatsapp,Messenger. my app overlay gets visible?is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible through implementing an accessibility service.

```
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource();
    if (source != null & source.getClassName().equals("android.widget.EditText")) {
        //...
    }
}
```

You also need to have the relevant permissions for that. Check  [AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = event.getSource() always returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33509285/accessibilitynodeinfo-nodeinfo-event-getsource-always-returns-null/33529747)